# Как добавить кнопку "Add +" для поля в Contact Forms 7 в Elementor?

Tags: contact-form7, elementor

Например, нужно заполнить поле с именем. Не одно, а несколько. Нужно, чтобы была кнопка добавить. И каждый раз, когда нажимаешь, появляется новое поле для ввода.
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю Вам подойдет вот этот плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-repeatable-fields/ . Я его устанавливал на вп 5.6 - отлично работал, думаю сейчас тоже не будет проблем.